# Close temporary tabs using aura / LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-apps, tab

I got a requirment from client that temporary tabs needs to be closed by clicking a button in home page. So after clicking that button all the temporary tabs as like in the below needs to be closed

[image]

I tried a lot and found that workspace API can do this but unfortunaletly workspace API will work for console apps and not normal lightning Apps.

So finding a way to acheive that all temp tabs needs to be closed in Ligtning apps using aura or LWC

Comment: Don't think this is possible, I'd be happy to be proven otherwise.